# How to scrape all url inside a columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

Sorry for the question, but I'm new to python and for me this problem is very difficult.

I'm working on this csv (https://www.kaggle.com/jtrofe/beer-recipes) and I need to do scraping.

The problem is that in the column (URL) of data frame there is a part of a link and the main part (https://www.brewersfriend.com) is not declared. I want to scrape the rating of various beers from every url.

For me this is very complicated.

I hope that someone can help me! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure the site allows scraping according it's policy? Haven't checked that. So generally speaking, I know that pandas can already extract tables from an url, but to me it seems this functionality has it's limits, so I guess you will have to implement some scraping logic. Maybe it helps you to give beautiful soup a try (imported by bs4 in python) and insert the scraped content in a dataframe. BS4 it is quite powerfull!

Comment: Beautiful soup expects to get the html (or xml) code and only is for parsing, where it is very powerfull. you need to retrieve the code yourself. You can use the "requests" library for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a url in the data snapshot on https://www.kaggle.com/jtrofe/beer-recipes. The actual url you want to scrape from is https://www.brewersfriend.com/ . Then for each line you would append the url from the dataset.

For example the first one to scrape would be: 
 https://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/recipe/view/1633/vanilla-cream-ale

In order to scrape this you could do something simple like:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url='https://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/recipe/view/1633/vanilla-cream-ale'
html = urlopen(url)
print(html.read())
#Then extract the rating from the html
```

Only issue is when I try and scrape it, I am getting a 403 Forbidden Error... but that would be a separate issue.

Once you get the scrape working you can loop through every datapoint and scrape the ratings. Hopefully this helps you get going!

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the POST request the page does to add additional rows and instead alter the records to be returned parameter to retrieve the total number of rows. You could either scrape the total number from the original page or hard code it in (given it is a fixed dataset). You can parse the json returned for all the links for the entire dataset and simply concatenate the domain and protocol onto the relative url as shown below.

Do check the T&Cs regarding using this endpoint/scraping.

```
import requests, re

p = re.compile(r'dataviewToken":"(.*?)"')
p1 = re.compile(r'"rowCount":(\d+)')

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.kaggle.com/jtrofe/beer-recipes')   
    token = p.findall(r.text)[0]
    rows = int(p1.findall(r.text)[0])
    data = {"jwe":{"encryptedToken": token},"source":{"type":3,"dataset":{"url":"jtrofe/beer-recipes","tableType":1,"csv":{"fileName":"recipeData.csv","delimiter":",","headerRows":1}}},"select":["BeerID","Name","URL","Style","StyleID","Size(L)","OG","FG","ABV","IBU","Color","BoilSize","BoilTime","BoilGravity","Efficiency","MashThickness","SugarScale","BrewMethod","PitchRate","PrimaryTemp"],"skip":0,"take": rows}
    base = 'https://www.brewersfriend.com'
    r = s.post('https://www.kaggleusercontent.com/services/datasets/kaggle.dataview.v1.DataViewer/GetDataView', json = data).json()
    links = [base + row['text'][2] for row in r['dataView']['rows']]]['rows']]
```

Comment: Did you try this?